# Accessing object attributes Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an array `arr = ["model", "engine", "year", ................]` where each element is an attribute name of `Car` model.
I am trying to push these specific attribute values to another array

```
Car.all.each do |mycar|
  another_array << arr.map{ |attr| mycar.attr }
end
```

This of course gives the expected `no method error .attr for <object>`. What is the correct way to do this ??
**EDIT**
*I know about `.send()` method but I found that some fields encrypted using attr-encrypted gem are not decrypted properly when I use .send(). So I have to try something else like this*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needn't anything Rails/ActiveRecord specific.

If you're sure the attributes are "safe" (that is, the users couldn't have meddled with the list, or you validated the method names before), you can simply use ruby's `send`:

```
mycar.send(attr) # dangerous
mycar.public_send(attr) # a bit less dangerous. Keep reading for the correct solution..
```

ActiveRecord does provide a shortcut for this, however (that does checking for you):

```
mycar[attr]
```

Comment: yes I know, I have been using .send method but since I use attr-encrypted gem I found some fields are not decrypted when using send method, rthats why I have to try somthing like this

Comment: you'll need to store your list with `encrypted_` before

Comment: then I won't get decrypted value

Comment: `a.b` and `a.send(:b)` are literally the same. Use the correct method name as described in `attr-encrypted`.

Comment: `public_send` is safer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `attributes`

```
Car.all.each do |mycar|
  another_array << mycar.attributes.slice("model", "engine", "year").values }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I cant use .values because att-encrypted uses 'encrypted_' prefix before attributes.